# Deny access to wp-admin with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Is their a way so protect access to wp-admin on WordPress with .htaccess but instead or wp-admin use another address.

**Example**

> If someone wants to access wp-admin will have to goto /admin and from
>   their they will be allow to goto wp-admin else if they direct access
>   wp-admin, then it should be denied.

Comment: Yes. There is a whole section to hardening your install and the wp-admin area.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress

Comment: @PanamaJack The article doesn't provide the answer what OP actually need.

Comment: @RahilWazir I didn't put it as an answer, that's why it's a comment. However a simple google search reveals several hacks. http://www.dalih.net/170/3-steps-to-change-the-url-wp-admin-folder-tested-with-wordpress-3-2-1/